# How to export from Blender to unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, blender

I have a simple object created from PLANE, in BLENDER version 2.72, where I edged the edges to the height. How do I correctly export the model to Unity3d I have version 4.7 to make all walls visible? Figure 2. Sorry for the wrong English. Thanks for your advice

Picture 1 in Blender
[image: picture in blender]

object export .obj in unity
[image: object export .obj in unity]

Comment: to export you just have to copy the .blend into your project assets folder

Comment: I copied the .blend file into folder, but when I turn around in a unit, the walls disappear, they are not still visible

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It belongs to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Faces(sides of your model) can only be visible on one side. For example, if you have a plane it will look like a large, flat square. But if you look at it from the bottom, it will be invisible. This is probably your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The walls may be upside down
because to solve you have to go back in blender, and go in edit mode

[image]

Click on the drop-down arrow

[image]

Then click on face orientation

[image]

If you see a red wall then you have to keep following otherwise this is not the right solution.

[image]

Select the red wall and click from above on Mesh then on Normals and finally on Flip

[image]

Now normally all walls should be blue

[image]

And click again on face orientation to see model back to normal

**I hope it works!**